# trying to upgrade @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap but it stays the same version

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.2
Node: 12.18.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.2
@angular/http                   5.2.11
@schematics/angular             10.1.2
@schematics/update              0.1001.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.3
```

I want to upgrade @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap to latest version 7.0.0.

```
npm @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap -version
6.14.5
```

When i try to upgrade to version 7.0.0 i get this:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0
Skipping installation: Package already installed
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/workspace'
Require stack:
- C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\schematics\ng-add\index.js
- C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\dagul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\dagul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\dagul\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-6sWgeN\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I removed node_modules and installed it again and still the same.
My package.json states that 7.0.0 is the version and when i try to add it again it adds 7.0.0 but when i run a version check i still have 6.14.5

```
PS C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client> npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nativescript/tslint-rules@0.0.5 requires a peer of tslint@^5.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nativescript/tslint-rules@0.0.5 requires a peer of typescript@^3.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @phenomnomnominal/tsquery@3.0.0 requires a peer of typescript@^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0 <---- THIS ONE!
removed 1 package, updated 1 package and audited 1635 packages in 89.645s

67 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
PS C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client> npm @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap -version
6.14.5 <--- WHY!?
PS C:\MyProjects\LunchTime\client>
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? Having a similar problem.

Comment: hmm i think the problem was that i was having a angular app with an express api inside of it. So it ended upp with two different node_modules folders

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good workaround but gets the job done for me: first, "npm uninstall @ng-boottrap/ng-bootstrap" and then: "npm install @ngbootstrap/ng-bootstrap"

Comment: Try doing ng update @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap